# Unable to modify Authorized Domain in firebase auth

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

> I am new to firebase and wanted to update the Authorized domains(was able to add domains a few weeks ago) for the authentication, but I am unable to delete or modify the domains. The website throw an "Error updating authorized domain list" error. Am I missing something?

Comment: How are you trying to add them? There's add domain button in the Firebase console.

Comment: Through the website, even the process of removing the added custom domains, occurs an error with "Error updating authorized domain list".

Comment: Weird, this only happens on google chrome, but not safari.

Comment: I had a similar error. Can you check if there is an error in the console of chrome's dev-tools? I had a similar issue, that was caused by a chrome extension modifying my CORS headers.

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue with the result that for any reasons one of the already listet domain was entered with `https://`.This produces an error. When you add a new url the old one in the list get send also with the request (look in dev console of your browser). If there are invalid values you get an error of invalid parameters (look also in dev console of your browser) but the user interface just say "error".
Its a little bit weird, maybe some month ago an entry with `https://` was possible.

I had to delete the entry `https://mydomain.de`, after that I was able to replace it with `mydomain.de` without and also any other new domain.

For sure just one possible reason of problems with whitelisting, but maybe it helps someone.

Comment: Maybe this works, I just had to login in safari and everything was fine. So apparently google products work better on safari :)

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue (using Chrome). I noticed it worked for Krueger
in Safari. I just opened up the Firebase authentication settings in Edge and had no problem adding a domain!

Answer (score 0):

For some reason outdated chrome browser versions show that error(when ever you try to update or change some configuration on firebase Auth setting, Update your chrome browser or use Firefox or other browsers. it works fine with firefox browser.